# Best way to implement ember request to server-side search / rest api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I have Ruby on Rails backend with search by Ransack (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). 
How I can implement filters. It is very important to search took place on the server side
I know that this can be done using query params, like:

```
@store.find('order', queryParams)
```

But by following this path I would have to add all model's fields in queryParams list in controller and add to route:

```
queryParams: {
  <field>: {
    refreshModel: true
  }
  ....
}
```

But I don't like this solution

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ember, however I have a similar setup: searching models using ransack and my requests are sent via GET/POST ajax request from a KendoUI client.

Here is my typical search string via GET
http://server.com/products/search.json?q[vendor_number_start]=122191
(in this case this returns two products, `" where vendor_number LIKE '122191%' "`)

Hers is how my request looks when I do POST (from Chrome dev console)

```
params: {utf8:✓, authenticity_token:SENSORED,…}
action: "search"
authenticity_token: "SENSORED"
commit: "Details"
controller: "products"
q: {vendor_number_eq:90802491}
vendor_number_eq: "90802491"
utf8: "✓"
```

Here is code from my controller that receives request with params and calls a search

```
@q = Product.ransack(params[:q])
@products = @q.result().order(params[:order]).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per])
```

I use kaminari to do pagination - that's where page & per parmas come from .

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I'm not using ember, so can't advise. I suggest to change the question to "Best way to implement ember request to server-side search / rest api". The way it's worded now - it reads as if you are asking about server side part and the format of the request that should be sent, not the ember example code.